# As and like, which one is more natural for this sentence?

Tags: as-like

> If it was an hour later, it'd be the same time **as** yesterday.

or

> If it was an hour later, it'd be the same time **like** yesterday.

I saw the comment that the first one is more natural than the second one, but I don't know why and wanna know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely 'as'. 'Like" is incorrect.

EDIT: I will try to explain the reason. I am not a grammarian, if anyone who's actually made a study of this sort of thing would chime in, I'd be interested myself.

'Like' is used for comparisons. You could use it in the following: "This happened at the same time before. Today is like yesterday."

'As', as an adverb (according to the dictionary), is used to relate the 'extent' of something, which is a little difficult to fit exactly into this situation. But *in your sentence* you are not comparing the two things; you are saying that, under some conditions, the extent of one thing is the same as the extent of the other.

As a native US English speaker, I find the explanation a little hard to hold onto. It is easier, for me, to understand the part about comparing two things than to state why this situation does not qualify as comparing two things. But that's as far as I've gotten with it, hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, so i added i want to know why at the last of this question. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

> If it was an hour later, it'd be like yesterday.
> If it was an hour later, it'd be the same time as yesterday.

We use "like" for things that are similar, "as" for things that are identical.   In the first sentence above, today isn't the same day as yesterday, but the two days would be similar.   In the second sentence, yesterday's time and today's time would be identical times.